# Resume Method in Android

Tags: java, android

I want resume the same Activity if i without complete filling the form and click on submit button and exit my Activity .And again i start my app its same Activity i want to start.How can do this.Can some one help me please.Thanks in Advance.

Here is my code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_details);

          SharedPreferences
          settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0); boolean
          firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);

          if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time 

          {
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
              editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true); 
              editor.commit();
              //execute your code for first time
          } 

          else 
          {     
              Intent iSubmit = new Intent(Registration_Form.this,Employee_List.class);
              startActivity(iSubmit);
              finish();
              //Default Activity startActivity(a); 
          }

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        databaseHelper.onOpen(db);

        et_CompanyName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CompanyName);
        et_EmployeeName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_EmployeeName);
        et_CompanyWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_CompanyWebSite);
        et_ContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ConatctNo);
        et_Email_Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_EmailId);

        radioGroup_FinancialYaer = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroupFinanncialYear);


        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final String stringEmail_Id = et_Email_Id.getText().toString()
                        .trim();

                final String stringCompanyWebsite = et_CompanyWebsite.getText()
                        .toString().trim();

                if ((et_CompanyName.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
                    et_CompanyName.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
                }

                else if (!et_CompanyName.getText().toString().trim()
                        .matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                    et_CompanyName.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                }

                else if ((et_EmployeeName.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
                    et_EmployeeName.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
                }

                else if (!et_EmployeeName.getText().toString().trim()
                        .matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                    et_EmployeeName.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                }

                else if ((et_CompanyWebsite.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
                    et_CompanyWebsite.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
                }

                else if (!isValidUrl(stringCompanyWebsite)) {
                    et_CompanyWebsite.setError("Invalid URL");
                }

                else if ((et_ContactNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
                    et_ContactNumber.setError("Field Can Not Be Empty !");
                }

                else if (!isValidEmail(stringEmail_Id)) {
                    et_Email_Id.setError("Invalid Email");
                }

                else

                {
                    String stringCompanyName = et_CompanyName.getText()
                            .toString().trim();
                    String stringContactNumber = et_ContactNumber.getText()
                            .toString().trim();
                    String stringEmployeeName = et_EmployeeName.getText()
                            .toString().trim();


                    int selectedId = radioGroup_FinancialYaer.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    Log.e("selectedId "," = " + selectedId);
                    radioButton_FinancialYaer = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                    strFinancialYear = radioButton_FinancialYaer.getText().toString().trim();
                    Log.e("strRadioButton "," = " + strFinancialYear);


                    databaseHelper.insertRegstrationDetails(stringCompanyName,
                            stringEmployeeName, stringCompanyWebsite,
                            stringContactNumber, stringEmail_Id, strFinancialYear);
                    System.out.println("Data Inserted Successfully !!! ");

                    Intent iSubmit = new Intent(Registration_Form.this,Staff_Employee_Details.class);
                    startActivity(iSubmit);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    // validating email id
    private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {

        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" + "\\@"
                + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" + "(" + "\\."
                + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" + ")+";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }


    private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
        Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
        if(m.matches())
            return true;
        else
        return false;
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
             AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration_Form.this);

             alertbox.setTitle("Do you wish to exit ?");
             alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { 
                    // finish used for destroyed activity
                     finish();
                 }
             });

             alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                         // Nothing will be happened when clicked on no button 
                         // of Dialog     
               }
             });

             alertbox.show();
         }
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }

}
```

Comment: You need an Splash Screen to check whether form was completely filled or not? So make SplashScreen and make it launcher screen, in onCreate() check SharedPref object and navigate to other screen based on value true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your `EditText` values in a table in your `Database`.

Keep an extra column called `count` in your table. When user presses `Submit` button increment the value of count on the basis of number of entries user has entered at that moment in your `EditText` and save it in database.

When user again launches your app, check value of count, if it is equal to your expected value route him as per your requirement, if it's less than expected then show your form activity, populate data from database.

You can implement this feature by using a **Splash Screen**.

**EDIT : WHAT YOU ACTUALLY WANTED**

If user presses back button and starts your application you will be directed to the same activity if it's your launcher activity, else you can check if all the fields aren't filled then you can save a `boolean` value in `SharedPreference` and check it's state while launching your app and launch this activity if it's true.

Comment: Thanks to reply , Sorry but i did not get you.

Comment: When i fill all the field and submit it's store the data in SQLite database.But when i have fill half form and does not submit i just exit the app and again i start the app. The Activity which i exited i want that Activity.

Comment: No , Actually If i have 10 EditText and the user enter only in 5 then i exit my app on click the onBackPressed Button without submit the EditText data which is entering , and then when i restart my app i want to same activity on start up.

Comment: Yah Right i want actually.